# CosmosDb slow changefeed performance with high partition key cardinality

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, event-sourcing

I'm currently building an application using Event Sourcing for IOT with Cosmos. Within the Cosmos documentation it states

> Have a high cardinality. In other words, the property should have a wide range of possible values.

I have 4 containers events, snapshots, leases and views.

Every document in the database has a synthetically created unique Partition Key by applying a new Guid to the end. I query the data back out by using the STARTSWITH query. So this has created the highest cardinality possible as every value is unique. I've chosen this approach due to different IOT devices sending varying volumes of data and trying to avoid hot partitions.

Once the events are in I have an Azure Function per each Materialized View sharing the same lease container and this is where the performance drops.

So as of right now I have 6 Views which means I have 6 Azure Functions to build each of them. I've tried increasing the RU's to 10,000 and horizontally scaling the Functions (App Service Plan). However, Cosmos is still stuck using a single Partition Key Range and each View still only using a single changefeed partition causing delays of over 6 hours sometimes for the Views to be accurate. So there's no scalability for more devices to come online.

Is using unique values for the Partition Key a bad design and should I accept certain hot partitions on a per day basis using something similar to id|day|month|year?

Or have I completely missed something else entirely?

**EDIT**
Some additional info

- Both the CosmosDb and Functions are hosted in the same region
- I can see by the App Service Plan that the CPU does jump to 100% during the change feed lag but additional instances don't get consumed as expected
- The lag is caused when we start ingesting more events, so the change feed / Functions can't keep up
- The only requests made in the function are to Cosmos, there's nothing external
- The leases don't fan out to help with the bigger workload

Below you can see that certain Views/Functions remain behind whilst others are catching up. I would have expected that they would work in parallel as they're individual Functions

[image: A graph of each View (Function)]

Comment: Could you quantify "performance drops" with regard to the change feed functions?

Comment: Also, are you seeing any throttling (429) reported in the monitoring of the Cosmos account?

Comment: Throttling is rare and only when a spike of events on the ingestion side happens. Changefeed / Views doesn't have any throttling.

Comment: I wonder what you'd see if you architected the change feed consumption as a just a fast process to get changed items into a Service Bus queue, then some asynchronous queue consumers could fan out as needed to handle the queued burst. I describe this kind of approach in a recent project here: https://youtu.be/Tht_RV5QPJ0?t=1470

Comment: I have considered this. Using a single lease to pull all the events from CF to a Service Bus Topic rather than Queue. Then change the Functions trigger to Service Bus or use a hosted service. I think I will try this today. It should also prove if this is a logical issue as the functions will still remain behind but the CF will be "realtime"

Comment: Not sure whether it's relevant here, but varying `MaxItemsPerInvocation` can make a dramatic difference to the delivery rate.  As an example, I have a feed that - for whatever reason - delivers only 8 items/s with this value set to 1.  With it set to 100, it delivers ~500/s, and with it set to 1000 it delivers ~10k/s.  (Whether you can atomically process multiple items per delivery is an important consideration you have to make for yourself).  I've profiled it and it seems to spend a fair bit of its time updating the lease after each invocation...

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to make sure the Function reads data as fast as possible, I’d start by taking a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-changefeed-functions#my-changes-take-too-long-to-be-received

You need to understand and profile where is the lag /delay in your Function execution. Scaling in the sense of instance volume, commonly helps if the bottleneck is CPU bound for example (because scaling effectively distributes part of the Change Feed processing to other machines). The Change Feed Trigger uses the Change Feed Processor underneath which is governed by this logic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor#dynamic-scaling (distributes leases across machines, where 1 lease represents a physical partition). In a scenario where you have 10 leases/physical partitions, then you can distribute the workload across 10 instances.
But again, this only helps in the measure the problem is CPU bound. If your Function code’s major time consumer are I/O operations (like, network requests to other services), then you’d need to figure out how to improve that, as having more machines available might not help in the way you think (throwing more CPU is not always the answer).

If you already made sure that the connectivity configuration is correct (reading from the closest region), you should profile your Function code to understand where the performance problem is.
Because the Change Feed needs to assert order (one of the features of Change Feed is that events are delivered in order) then new events can only be read if the previous ones are processed. If you are ingesting data at X/docs per second and your Function is processing at Y/docs per second where X is much higher than Y, then your problem is your processing logic is slower and it will potentially always lag behind.

**EDIT**: After your new information, it sounds like something is up on the Function code when the volume of events increases. As mentioned, parallelism is based on # of leases which currently is based off [physical partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#physical-partitions). 1 lease = 1 physical partition = soft cap of 1 instance can process the work, as new partitions are added as your data grows, new leases are added dynamically, more instances can be leveraged.

My recommendation is still to double click on why the number of events increasing makes the Function code increase its latency. There is something in the state or logic that lags processing the more events it goes through and that potentially is the key/reason.

Comment: Would you expect Functions to be able to process at equivalent or better rate than a dedicated always-on ChangeFeedProcessor process, all else equal? I've guessed it would be better to go dedicated and remove Functions from the equation, but haven't done a proper test.

Comment: Considering similar machine and environment, it wouldn't really make a difference, because Functions simply uses Change Feed processor. So having X VM instances of Y size running CFP or having X Function instances of the same Y size, would be more or less the same. Different compute services might have different limits or SKU sizes, and there are other aspects to consider (would you like to maintain the OS also in the VM?)

Comment: I've edited the post which answers a bit more of your questions. So are we saying that ALL partition keys being unique is fine and not causing this issue? Changefeed asserting order is perfect due to using Event Sourcing. In regards to Dynamic Scaling, are you saying that this isn't possible by only using the Function Trigger? I can see in my leases container each function has it's own lease but it's always partition 0

Comment: That means that your container has only a single physical partition (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#physical-partitions) as your collection grows, new partitions will be added dynamically, and new leases will be added, effectively increasing the potential degree of parallelism. But 90% of the time, this is not really the bottleneck for processing speed, that is why I would focus on performance investigation on the Function code.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta So I found the Azure Function was struggling with an in memory list of documents, but only when there's a big lag. However, after 3GB of data and over 2M documents I still only have a single physical partition. So I'm now questioning whether a unique partition key for every record is actually bad practice. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @niko619 Please see the physical partition documentation. A physical partition can hold 50GB of information. So if you are storing 3GB, it's within a single partition. Partition key definition is an orthogonal topic which depends on how you query data also (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey). The number of physical partitions is based off your data storage.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta what if I have only one physical partition but my work is CPU bound. Is there any way to divide one physical partition into multiple delegate consumers? Or do I have to use pull model for this use case?

Comment: Sure, you can do a scatter pattern, grab the change feed results, put it on a Storage or Service Bus queue and then have QueueTriggers.